# XmlNode Value vs InnerText

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm creating a ping application for school with an XML full of URLs.
I lost an hour because of `XmlNode.Value` was resulting in a null.

Then I changed it into `InnerText` and it worked fine.

Now I was wonder what's the difference because MSDN says that .Value returns the value of the node and `InnerText` returns  the concatenated values of the node and all its child nodes.

Can someone explain this for me please?

```
<sites>
<site>
    <url>www.test.be</url>
    <email>test@test.be</email>
</site>
<site>
    <url>www.temp.be</url>
    <email>temp@temp.be</email>
</site>
<site>
    <url>www.lorim.ipsum</url>
    <email>interim.address@domain.com</email>
</site></sites>
```

Comment: You might want to post a sample of your XML file.

Comment: @FrazellThomas - the differences between .Value and .InnerText can be easily understood without seeing his XML

Comment: If you debug and use the immediate window you may be able to save yourself a lot of time in debugging things. It allows you to execute code based on the current context and will write out all of the properties and their values of the XElement. This approach would allow you to easily glance at the object graph and verify that Value is null, but InnerText contains your value. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If, for example, your XML looks like `<Foo>Bar</Foo>` then "Bar" is actually considered a separate node: an `XmlText` node (sub-classed from `XmlNode`). The `Value` property of that `XmlText` node would be "Bar".

"Foo" is considered to be an `XmlElement` (also sub-classed from `XmlNode`). `XmlNode.Value` returns different things based on the type of node it is. See [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) which shows that `Value` always returns `null` for `Element` nodes.

The `InnerText` of the Foo node returns "Bar" because it concatenates the values of its children (in this case, only the one `XmlText` node).

Comment: Note: the xpath for selecting the TextNode would be "Foo/text()"

Comment: Hi Robert! How can I use serialization with this? If I take your example <Foo>Bar</Foo>, I will have a class called "Foo" but which property should I have to get "Bar" serialized inside it?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar situation. What I did is, I picked the first child of the current node and checked if it is XMLtext, then displayed its value.

```
XmlNodeList xNList = xDOC.SelectNodes("//" + XMLElementname);

foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNList)
{
    if (xNode.ChildNodes.Count == 1 && 
        xNode.FirstChild.GetType().ToString() == "System.Xml.XmlText")
    {
        XMLElements.Add(xNode.FirstChild.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        XMLElements.Add("This is not a Leaf node");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML specification is very picky about terminology and what constitutes what type of XML object. As mentioned, `element` doesn't have a value. This is specific to `attribute` (and probably a couple of other node types) because `attribute` has a syntax that `element` does not, i.e. `name='value'`.

If you think that's confusing, check out the difference between child and descendant, or the Root Node and the Document Element!

Comment: Just more reasons to abandon XML for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx), `Value` property of `XmlNodeType.Element` returns:

> null. You can use the XmlElement.InnerText or XmlElement.InnerXml properties to access the value of the element node.

Comment: Is it possible for .InnerXml to return null? From my brief testing, it doesn't appear so, e.g., when I create a node, explicitly assign `node.InnerXml = null;` and then test for `node.InnerXml == null;` it's false. Instead, `node.InnerXml == string.Empty;` is true. Is this behavior I can rely on? MSDN docs are silent on this.

Answer (score 0):

As url element is the leaf node, the InnerText(also InnerXml) property contains the element value. For element nodes, the value property will be null as shown in msdn documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value(v=VS.110).aspx.