# How to Set value to XmlNode without using InnerText

Tags: c#, xml

I want to set value to some XmlNode but i dont want to use InnerText - is there some other way  ?

the xml that i need to have is

```
  <ns1:id>123456</ns1:id>
```

so i did this

```
   XmlNode node = doc.CreateElement( doc.DocumentElement.Prefix, "id", doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI );
   node.InnerText = "123456";
```

but i want to do it without using the InnerText  ... => is there a way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps just use the `Value` property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx

Comment: try to use the value ... not working :(

Comment: `Value` might not work properly with XmlElement (at least that's what I recall at the moment). An alternative would be `InnerXml`. I feel OP wants something else than just another property with a different name. And if not, I wonder why `InnerText` is not desirable if it gets the job done.

Comment: I think you should be able to [append text node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createtextnode.aspx)... Also providing reason why `InnerText` is not acceptable may help with answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7877609/81053 try `node.FirstChild.Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text is instance of one (more more) nodes with node type text. So if you want you can directly append/replace text nodes to your element.

[XmlDocument.CreateTextNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createtextnode.aspx) contains a sample on how one can do that:

```
//Create a new node and add it to the document. 
//The text node is the content of the price element.
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("price");
XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode("19.95");
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
doc.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(text);
```

Note that you may need to remove old child text nodes first.