# C# reading an xml file, node value returns as blank

Tags: c#, xml

So basically, working on a xml file, that looks like this:

```
...
<city id="thatstheid">
  <country id="anotherid"> VALUE </country>
</city>
...
```

and i read the stuff i need using:

```
XmlDocument doc;//let's say this is the file im reading

XmlNode cityNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("city");
cityname = cityNode.Attributes["id"].Value;

XmlNode countryNode = cityNode.SelectSingleNode("country");
countryname = countryNode.Value;
```

The problem here being that

```
countryname = countryNode.Value;
```

brings back an empty value, even though there's something inside.

If i try to get any atributes from the inside like this :

```
countryname = countryNode.Attributes["id"].Value;
```

it works fine, so i don't know what's the problem.

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877609/xmlnode-value-vs-innertext

Comment: @JeffreyWieder Thanks a lot, was interested why it worked the way it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try InnerText

```
countryname = countryNode.InnerText;
```

Comment: yeah, seems to work, thanks a lot, any idea why .value doesn't work?

Edit: nevermind, saw the comment on my main post.